# Can't update state in react useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I can't update the data in useEffect, even after using async.
Note: I don't to add data as dependency in useEffect as I want to fetch data only once

````
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function RenderBody() {

    let [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let response = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson);
            await setData((prevData) => {
                return {...prevData, responseJson}
            });
            console.log(data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            {data.length > 0 ? data.map(element => {
                return <>
                    <div>{element.brand}</div>
                    <div>{element.price}</div>
                </>
            }) : <div>Nothing to display</div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default RenderBody ```
````

Comment: `console.log(data);` This will only ever log the old state. None of your code makes any attempt to change the local variable `data`. `setData` does not change local variables, it just asks react to render the component again sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't update the data in useEffect

Sure you can, and you are.  But what are you updating it **to**?  The state value is initially an array:

```
let [data, setData] = useState([])
```

And initially the UI doesn't display anything because it checks the `length` property of the array:

```
data.length > 0 ? ...
```

Then you update state to **an object**:

```
await setData((prevData) => {
    return {...prevData, responseJson}
});
```

Since this object has no `length` property, `data.length` is `undefined`.  And `undefined` is not `> 0`, so the UI continues to successfully not display anything.

Assuming `responseJson` is an object to be added to the array, it looks like you just want to spread into an array instead of an object:

```
setData((prevData) => {
    return [...prevData, responseJson]
});
```

(Note also that I removed the `await`, since using `await` on something that isn't *awaitable* is a no-op, so the keyword isn't doing anything useful there.)

---

As an aside... Since this effect only occurs once when the component first loads, and it's known that the state value is empty, you can do without the `prevData` approach entirely and simplify:

```
setData([responseJson]);
```

---

Additionally... You can remove the `console.log(data);` on the line after updating state.  This is just going to log an empty array to the console, and you already know the initial state was an empty array because it's explicitly defined as such in the code.

If you want to log the new state, that value is in `responseJson`, which you already logged.

Answer (score 0):

You setting the data to an object instead of an array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let response = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson);
            await setData((prevData) => {
                return [...prevData, responseJson]
            });
            console.log(data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```